# Choose which devices to show in Task Manager Performace tab

Tags: windows-10, vmware, task-manager

Since I installed VMware Workstation 16 Player, it added 2 "devices" to the task manager `Performance` tab: `VMware Network Adapter VMnet1` and `VMware Network Adapter VMnet8`. They don't give me any useful information and just make it difficult to access my actual WI-Fi information (misclicks, small window, &c.). Can I Hide or remove them from the list somehow?

[image: A partial view of my task manager]